# Internet Provider with "Private WAN" to the clients?

Tags: networking, lan, nmap, traceroute, wan

This is strange. How this actually works. So far I know it is "impossible" to have a network like this.
I'm going to explain in details how my network works.

I have a LAN. 192.168.1.0/24 and router is on 192.168.1.1, This router has a public address.
I can share the IP address because I'm running there a server for tests nothing more. It is ok so far.
Now the magic happens.
When I trace the route to an IP I got this (To google DNS):

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  zonhub.home (192.168.1.1)  1.160 ms  1.676 ms  1.340 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.137.211.97 (10.137.211.97)  12.915 ms  12.526 ms  12.145 ms
 4  10.255.49.90 (10.255.49.90)  10.349 ms 10.255.49.102 (10.255.49.102)  11.483 ms  11.042 ms
 5  80.157.128.249 (80.157.128.249)  34.577 ms 80.157.130.41 (80.157.130.41)  32.917 ms 80.157.130.33 (80.157.130.33)  30.602 ms
 6  mad-sa3-i.MAD.ES.NET.DTAG.DE (217.5.95.161)  33.396 ms 80.157.128.22 (80.157.128.22)  27.107 ms mad-sa3-i.MAD.ES.NET.DTAG.DE (217.5.95.161)  29.510 ms
 7  80.157.128.22 (80.157.128.22)  28.050 ms 72.14.235.20 (72.14.235.20)  32.767 ms 80.157.128.22 (80.157.128.22)  27.932 ms
 8  72.14.235.20 (72.14.235.20)  29.780 ms 72.14.235.18 (72.14.235.18)  27.020 ms  26.706 ms
 9  216.239.43.233 (216.239.43.233)  49.456 ms 209.85.240.191 (209.85.240.191)  44.034 ms 216.239.43.233 (216.239.43.233)  51.935 ms
10  72.14.236.191 (72.14.236.191)  53.374 ms 209.85.253.20 (209.85.253.20)  50.699 ms 216.239.43.233 (216.239.43.233)  44.918 ms
11  209.85.251.231 (209.85.251.231)  50.151 ms * 216.239.49.45 (216.239.49.45)  47.309 ms
12  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  51.536 ms  50.180 ms  45.505 ms
```

What is that 2nd, 3rd and 4th hop? How can it be on class A private address when 192.168.1.1 is running the NAT service where I have my LAN and my external 3 publics addresses (yes I have 3 and is 3 "class A" IP's on 88,89,93 network).

Another thing is how on 4th hop we have the 2nd octet 255?

Anyone feel free to traceroute my no-ip domain: synackfiles.no-ip.org
Just don't mess with my router (it blocks if you port scan or fail to log in in ssh or http auth so you get banned for this. If you just traceroute it is fine) :P

Now, second magic and weird stuff happens.
I'm going to run nmap. So i GOT THIS:

```
sudo nmap -sV -A -O 10.137.211.113 -vv -p 1-500 -Pn

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-14 15:24 WET
NSE: Loaded 93 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:24
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:24, 0.04s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 15:24
Scanning 10.137.211.113 [500 ports]
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 30.40% done; ETC: 15:26 (0:01:11 remaining)
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 60.30% done; ETC: 15:26 (0:00:40 remaining)
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 15:26, 101.14s elapsed (500 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 15:26
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against 10.137.211.113
Initiating Traceroute at 15:26
Completed Traceroute at 15:26, 9.05s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:26
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 15:26, 0.01s elapsed
NSE: Script scanning 10.137.211.113.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 15:26
Completed NSE at 15:26, 0.00s elapsed
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Nmap scan report for 10.137.211.113
Host is up (0.0010s latency).
All 500 scanned ports on 10.137.211.113 are filtered
Device type: general purpose|specialized|media device
Running: Barrelfish, Microsoft Windows 2003|PocketPC/CE|XP, Novell NetWare 3.X, Siemens embedded, Telekom embedded
OS CPE: cpe:/o:barrelfish:barrelfish cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2003::sp1 cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2003::sp2 cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_ce cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_xp:::professional cpe:/o:novell:netware:3.12
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
TCP/IP fingerprint:
SCAN(V=6.00%E=4%D=11/14%OT=%CT=%CU=%PV=Y%G=N%TM=5284EBAB%P=armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi)
T7(R=Y%DF=N%TG=80%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=R)
U1(R=N)
IE(R=N)


TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   2.32 ms zonhub.home (192.168.1.1)
2   ... 30

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
NSE: Starting runlevel 2 (of 2) scan.
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 122.65 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 1109 (49.620KB) | Rcvd: 4 (200B)
```

Well, this is odd. I don't know how my country's WAN is designed and built.
I'm from Portugal and my ISP is "ZON TVCABO". You can search now. :P
This is very very very interesting..

Sincerely,

int3

Answer (score 0):

- I cannot tell you how your providers WAN is built - but in order to
  save public IPs - one can design an ISPs internal network with private
  IPs. The routers that are not needed to be available from public will
  have private IPs only - the IPs assigned to you can be routed to your
  uplink over routers that are ISP internally only.
- the 2nd hop has no tracing allowed, but allows to forward them.
- the 4th - 10.255.x.x is a private IP in the 10.0.0.0/8 A range. (you 
  can use numbers from 0-255)